# maven webapp, xml never loaded

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, web-applications, maven-3

In my webapp in Eclipse, my xml configuration files are never loaded when I launch the web project.
Can you explain me how I can add the xml files in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF to the context loader please ?

My 3 files are :

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>
        index.jsp
        index.html
    </welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>


<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
/WEB-INF/application-context.xml,
/WEB-INF/cxf-servlet.xml
</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

cxf-servlet.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
   xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">

<!-- these are included in the dependency jar -->
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml"/>


<!-- soap container -->
<jaxws:endpoint
        id="computerWS"
        implementor="#computerService"
        address="/computer"
        />
</beans>
```

application-context.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<import resource="classpath:serviceContext.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:bindingContext.xml" />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.excilys.formation.webservice.service" />

<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang"></property>
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that tomcat deploys your application. If you are not getting any error during the deployment based on your application, it is probably tomcat issue.

Comment: Hey, I don't know if it was a similar error or not but I did Maven -> Update Project, and a clean install of my project. It's working right now !